# Modify classes.dex and repack .apk file

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering

I want to modify classes.dex file in .apk file of my Android application and make a new .apk file. I already know how to decompile .apk file using tools such as apktool and then recompile it. My issue is to modify classes.dex file exactly, not a .smali code.

I tried to make a .zip archive with modified classes.dex file and to change it's extension to .apk, but I failed to install this .apk on my Android gadget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to decode an application without disassembling the `classes.dex` file to smali. In Apktool you can utilize the `-s / --skip-sources` parameter to avoid this. Apktool will simply pass on the `classes.dex` instead of disassembling it.

Then you can modify it directly however you are. Then recompile with (`apktool b`) and it will copy the `classes.dex` into final built apk.